# Confusing holidays

Tags: knowledge, language, literature

Tired of playing games, you decide to take a holiday.

You first location, you wander about for a bit, completely lost in the crowds until finally the relative you were supposed to meet spots you. They laugh and say

> 'Finally, I have been searshing ewerrywhere for you Hugo!'

Your second location, you get even more lost. Again a relative pulls you out of the crowd and says

> 'Zere you are Charlie! I nearly gave up looking for you!'

You leave both locations anxious to get back to your normal life, and go back home.

**What is your usual name and where did you go?**

Note:

Your usual name *isn't* Hugo or Charlie

Hint:

> They are from a children's book, but I'd be surprised if anyone hadn't heard of them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is in

> Sweden

and the second is in

> France.

Your usual name is

> Wally.

You are wearing

> red-and-white stripy clothes and a silly hat.

In case all is not yet obvious:

> There is a series of puzzle-books, the first book and the series generally being called "Where's Wally?". The title character wears a distinctive horizontally-striped shirt and bobbly hat. Each page of each book features a scene packed with people, exactly one of whom is identifiable as Wally. There are often other things in the picture with features that resemble (for instance) his characteristic shirt. "Wally" is not a normal name everywhere in the world, for one reason or another, so in many countries the books are published in versions where his name is something else. For instance, in the USA he is Waldo.

So

> he has gone on holiday wanting a change from playing his hide-and-seek games -- but of course he finds it happening anyway, which is why his family keep pulling him out of crowds and saying how long they've been looking. In Sweden he is known as Hugo and in France as Charlie, so of course they call him that.

Comment: Correct! Finally someone got that... Can you explain some of the clues? Like being lost in the crowd and playing games?

Comment: I thought it was obvious once I said who the protagonist is :-). But yes, I'll edit in some more details.

Comment: OK, done. I see you edited the answer too, but my version happened to contain the extra information you added. (But the variant name you added is just as much a variant as Hugo or Charlie, and I maintain that there is only one canonical name.)

Comment: Fair enough, and well done on spotting what no one else did :P

Comment: Ta. (For what it's worth, I got it almost instantly. Just one of those things that you either happen to think of or not, I think.)

Comment: And for anyone who might find the accents (questionably) offensive I got them from [here](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130414151628AAbqHyC) and [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080615233821AAdiMJT)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Flagged for Yahoo Answers links :-O

Answer (score 1):

***Partial Answer***:

First Location:

> I can't quite place this accent...

Second Location:

> France

because

> It's quite common for native French speakers to say a "Z" or "TZ" sound instead of a "TH" sound in words like "The", etc.

My name:

> Still working on my name (Yes, I have amnesia)

Comment: For the sake of others, France is correct

Comment: Guessing Austria for location 1. Maybe Germany.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are:

> Hugo.  You are vacationing where your identical twin, Charlie, lives.
>
>  Charlie finds you the first time, and knows it is you because you were supposed to meet (and because you are, obviously, not Charlie).
>  Some other relative of yours (who is also a relative of Charlie) finds you the second time, but was looking for Charlie and thinks they found him when they found you.

As for where you went,

> I'm bad at accents. Charlie seems to be Russian, so perhaps so are you.
>  The relative who addresses you as Charlie is German? Swiss? I'd guess Charlie left Mother Russia and now lives in Germany or Switzerland, where you vacationed to visit.

Comment: No no no, sorry I didn't make it clear. Hugo and Charlie aren't the usual names